# Clean way to push results of multiple methods into an array

Tags: ruby, refactoring

I have the following Ruby code, which calls the same function multiple times with different arguments, and pushes the results into a common array.

```
people_relations = []
people.zip(people_addresses).map do |person, address|
  people_relations.push(createRelation(person, address))
end
people.zip(people_ph_numbers).map do |person, phone_number|
  people_relations.push(createRelation(person, phone_number))
end
people.zip(people_aliases).map do |person, _alias|
  people_relations.push(createRelation(person, _alias))
end

def createRelation(e1, e2)
  [true, false].sample ? CurrentRelation.new(e1, e2) : PastRelation.new(e1, e2)
end
```

This code works just fine, but I feel like this is not the idiomatic Ruby way of doing things, and can be improved by compressing the code into less lines or made to look cleaner.

Is there a better way to write the code that appears above?

Comment: What's the meaning of the ternary with `[true, false].sample`?

Comment: @SebastianPalma It's my way of randomly choosing between creating a `PastRelation` or `CurrentRelation` object.

Comment: @SebastianPalma The definition of the function is already there, down the bottom.

Comment: Sorry, my bad...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably go with a [`transpose`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-transpose) -> [`flat_map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) solution for this myself, for instance given:

```
def CreateRelation(person, relationship)
  if [true, false].sample
    "#{person} is currently related to #{relationship}"
  else
    "#{person} used to be related to #{relationship}"
  end
end

people = ['Person 1', 'Person 2', 'Person 3']
addresses = ['Person 1 Address', 'Person 2 Address', 'Person 3 Address']
phone_numbers = ['Person 1 Phone', 'Person 2 Phone', 'Person 3 Phone']
aliases = ['Person 1 AKA', 'Person 2 AKA', 'Person 3 AKA']
```

We can stick those 4 arrays into a single array and then `transpose` them, so the first element of each ends up in an array with each other, the second in another, and the last in a third:

```
[people, addresses, phone_numbers, aliases].transpose # => [
#  ["Person 1", "Person 1 Address", "Person 1 Phone", "Person 1 AKA"],
#  ["Person 2", "Person 2 Address", "Person 2 Phone", "Person 2 AKA"],
#  ["Person 3", "Person 3 Address", "Person 3 Phone", "Person 3 AKA"]]
```

and then you can `flat_map` those by calling `CreateRelation`:

```
result = [people, addresses, phone_numbers, aliases].transpose.flat_map do |person, *relations|
  relations.map { |relationship| CreateRelation(person, relationship) }
end
#["Person 1 used to be related to Person 1 Address",
# "Person 1 used to be related to Person 1 Phone",
# "Person 1 used to be related to Person 1 AKA",
# "Person 2 is currently related to Person 2 Address",
# "Person 2 used to be related to Person 2 Phone",
# "Person 2 is currently related to Person 2 AKA",
# "Person 3 is currently related to Person 3 Address",
# "Person 3 used to be related to Person 3 Phone",
# "Person 3 used to be related to Person 3 AKA"]
```

Or, at that point you could stick with just iterating and pushing, if you don't want to `map`/`flat_map`.

---

The more I think about it, the more I think I'd go with `transpose` -> `each_with_object`, instead of `flat_map`...less "create an array and then throw it away", I'll leave this with `flat_map` though because it is another option and @Sebastian Palma has `each_with_object` covered.

Comment: I liked this one most because it is the most concise and "artistic" solution. Thanks!

Comment: @JavascriptLoser As an aside since I have no overt objections to this answer `Array#zip` can accept any number of `Arrays` so `people.zip(addresses, phone_numbers, aliases)` would have the same result as `[people, addresses, phone_numbers, aliases].transpose`

Answer (score 2):

You could create an array that contains all the people "attributes" you're going to use, and with `Enumerable#each_with_object` you can assign an initial array to fill with the result of each call to createRelation():

```
attributes = [people_addresses, people_ph_numbers, people_aliases]
relations = people.each_with_object([]).with_index do |(person, memo), index|
  attributes.each do |attribute|
    memo << createRelation(person, attribute[index])
  end
end
```

Comment: this is very very very hard to read and understand, but contemplates the answer like a charm. Should be consider the correct answer.